# How to upgrade firmware on OKI MB441? Device not found in Firwmare upgrade tool

Tags: multi-function-printer

How to upgrade firmware on OKI MB441?

When I am trying to use `Firmware Upgrade Tool`, I get error `Device not found`. This error is not listed in troubleshooting manual.

[image]

Device is connected to LAN, I can print on it and scan from it.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the environmental settings and set the IP range, so that the IP of your printer is in between the first IP and the last.

So if your printers IP is *192.168.178.8*

Then do this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response - I've just experienced the same problem myself,
and the answer given helped me somewhat.

I notice, however, that the 'Network search range' seems to be a bit mask instead of a 'range' and so to find my printer on A.B.C.241 I could use either of:
A.B.C.255 or
A.B.C.241
but not, for example, a range on consecutive lines as given by Phil Roggenbuck.

I'm not sure why the default search range of 255.255.255.255 failed to work - perhaps my gateway/router didn't like the fw updater scanning non-local ranges.

Comment: Too bad, it didn't work for me. I also see the range as a mask, so I tried A.B.C.255, or the full ip, both without success. I also experimented with the windows firewall, and tries using the USB port. all without success (MB441, Windows 10, FWUP_010502_8_270533.exe)

Comment: A.B.C.255 worked for me