# How to upgrade firmware on OKI MC562dn from USB-Stick?

Tags: usb, printer, firmware

Unfortunately all my attempts to connect my OKI MC562dn with the official firmware update tool fail. The hints given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1180437/how-to-upgrade-firmware-on-oki-mb441-device-not-found-in-firwmare-upgrade-tool) doesn't work for me. The tool can't find any device in the network.

The strange thing is: The printer works fine in general. I can print from several windows PCs in the same network without problems, in color, black&white and duplex. I can ping the printer. I can manage the device with the webserver reachable at 192.168.1.21. I can even scan documents and fotos from my OKI MC562 to several different locations in my home network.

To update the firmware I also tried to connect the printer to a laptop and his USB Port. The same thing: I can print, but the update tool doesn't find the printer.

**How can I update my OKI MC562 with the [newest available firmware](https://www.oki.com/uk/printing/support/firmware/colour-multifunction/44952204/) and the use of a USB stick?**

The [OKI documentation](http://my.okidata.com/idocs2.nsf/644f62e290bebe228525694d00496c00/0b85eb8f457d7b7785257cb3005dbae0/$FILE/USB%20Update%20Firmware%20Universal%20V2.pdf) isn't clear enough for me to find all necessary files and the needed "model specific folder structure" to get it working. Has anyone done this succesfully?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your firmware update? I'm suspecting that I have such old firmware that the OverTheAir update protocol is not even implemented (2011-2012 something). I've not tried it yet but I suspect that you just format a flash drive and put the `.bin` file on it. Will try that as soon as I get hold of a working USB drive...

Comment: @thoni56 Yes, but only with the very friendly help from a certified OKI engineer. He sent me the necessary tool to update the firmware. This tool is only available for such 'specialists' and will not be made public. (This was also the information I got from the helpdesk and from mail agents at OKI Europe).